# How to enter a previously closed pipenv virtual environment

Tags: terminal, macos-catalina, pipenv

I had been working in a pipenv virtual environment for the past few days (mac OS Catalina), leaving that terminal window open. I've exited the environment using

```
deactivate
```

and went back to my home directory, but now I am trying to re-enter that virtual environment (named "lambdata_abw")...

I've tried

```
pipenv shell
pipenv lambdata_abw shell
pipenv open lambdata_abw
pipenv open PATH
```

but there's something I'm clearly missing as none of these have worked ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was I had not actually exited pipenv via `exit`, so it was unclear what directory I was in.

Once I exited and then returned to the proper directory at PATH, `pipenv shell` worked as expected.

Comment: how did you exit if you couldn't get back in?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by navigating to your virtual environment dir and then source bin/activate.

```
$ source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
```